# How can I say "really!?" in Italian?

Tags: translation

> – I'm in love! 
>   – Really!?

What is a good match in Italian for the word "really"? Here the word does not carry any doubt, just excitement.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Tim!

Comment: Grazie @Charo !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best match for "really" in the context that you mention is "davvero":

> – I'm in love! 
>   – Really!?

> – Mi sono innamorato/a! 
>   – Davvero!?

Comment: Another possibility is *Sul serio?!*

Comment: It depends on context. You could also use: "Sono innamorato/a" - "Veramente?" (In order to express a disbelief or perplexity for example)

Comment: But the OP explicitly mentioned «Here the word does not carry any doubt», @Arcsn.

Comment: You can also use *Ma dài?!*

Answer (score 2):

Another common option is:

> Non ci credo/non posso crederci (I can't believe it).